# Most idiomatic way in React/Redux to decouple UI state from global storage state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

**EDIT: This seems to be due to some issue about calling APIs in the same update you make UI updates:**

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32867

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35037

I have a huge UI/UX problem - I have a set of buttons that I want to update the styles of as soon as possible, and then I also have some other component with a whole loading process that can take quite a bit of time to do. Right now, the buttons are taking as long as the loading component to update, and that's TERRIBLE UX.

Both components rely on the same data - my categories slice, which looks like this:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [];

export const categoriesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "categories",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    categoriesSave: (state, action) => {
      state = [...state, action.payload];
      return state;
    },
    categoriesSaveAll: (state, action) => {
      if (state === action.payload) {
        return state;
      }
      return action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { categoriesSave, categoriesSaveAll } =
  categoriesSlice.actions;

export default categoriesSlice.reducer;
```

My categories component that looks like this:

```
const CatsModalChild = (props: any) => {
  const reduxCategories = useSelector(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.categories
  );
  const [localCategories, setLocalCategories] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const categories = useCategoriesAPIQuery({ taxon: props.taxon });
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const categoryChange = (value: any) => {
    let _selectedCategories = [...selectedCategories];

    if (_selectedCategories.indexOf(value) === -1) {
      _selectedCategories.push(value);
    } else {
      _selectedCategories = _selectedCategories.filter(
        (item) => item !== value
      );
    }
    setSelectedCategories(_selectedCategories);
  };

  const onCategoriesSelectionsChange = () => {
    if (categories.status === "fulfilled") {
      let selectedCats = selectedCategories.map((x: any) => x.value);
      let deleteCats = new Set(categories.data.map((x: any) => x.value));
      // @ts-ignore
      const difference = localCategories.filter((x) => !deleteCats.has(x));
      const cats = [...selectedCats, ...difference];
      props.categoriesSaveAll(cats);
    }
  };

  const categoriesMapper = () => {
    let _selectedCategories: any = [];
    for (let cat of localCategories) {
      let catVal = categories.data.filter((item: any) => item.value === cat);
      let selectedCat = catVal[0];
      if (selectedCat) {
        _selectedCategories.push(selectedCat);
      }
    }
    setSelectedCategories(_selectedCategories);
  };

  // This was an unsuccessful attempt to decouple my redux store from my local state.

  useEffect(() => {
    const _localCategories = [...reduxCategories];
    setLocalCategories(_localCategories);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    onCategoriesSelectionsChange();
  }, [selectedCategories, categories]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (categories.data?.length > 0) {
      categoriesMapper();
    }
  }, [categories]);

  if (categories.status == "pending") {
    return <Box />;
  }

  return (
    <MultipleSelect
      items={categories.data}
      selectedItems={selectedCategories}
      onPress={categoryChange}
    />
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
... irrelevant now, moved all state out of here
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: any) {
  let actions = bindActionCreators(
    {
      categoriesSaveAll,
    },
    dispatch
  );
  return { ...actions, dispatch };
}

export const CatsModal = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(memo(CatsModalChild));
```

And finally my article component:

```
const Articles = (props) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView
      minH={600}
      //contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: "flex-start" }}
      zIndex={10}
      _dark={{
        bg: "gray.700",
      }}
      _light={{
        bg: "gray.100",
      }}
    >
      <Helmet>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>{props.title}</title>
        <link rel="canonical" href="http://pandaist.com/news" />
      </Helmet>
      <Center py={[25, 25, 25, 50, 50]}>
        <Heading
          fontSize={["4xl", "6xl", "6xl"]}
          _light={{
            color: "black",
          }}
          _dark={{
            color: "white",
          }}
        >
          {props.title}
        </Heading>
      </Center>
      <Filters hideCalendar={props.hideCalendar} />
      <RecentArticles {...props} title="Recent Articles" taxon={props.taxon} />
      <Box alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
        <Categories taxon={props.taxon} />
      </Box>
      <CategoryArticles {...props} taxon={props.taxon} />
      <Box h={50} />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    settings: state.settings,
    category: state.categories,
    resetdate: state.resetdate,
    date: state.date,
    readarticles: state.readarticles,
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  let actions = bindActionCreators({ settingsSave }, dispatch);
  return { ...actions, dispatch };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(memo(Articles));
```

My biggest problem is my UI updates - when I remove: `props.categoriesSaveAll(cats)` everything is instant and the UI is snappy. I've tried to decouple the UI with putting the data into local state via a useEffect hook, but that still doesn't solve the problem.

For some reason, whenever I call `props.categoriesSaveAll(cats)`, wherever I call it, it causes this problem. If I put a wait time on it before it fires, the UI buttons update instantly (but freeze until the function runs).

How can I successfully decouple the UI update from the global store save, if I want initial population of the data to be based on the global store?

**EDIT: My CategoryArticles component, where the actual query is happening:**

```
const CategoryArticlesChild = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [articleGroups, setArticleGroups] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(false);
  const { data } = useCategoryArticlesAPIQuery(query ?? skipToken);

  const loadArticlesByCategory = async () => {
    const hsks = await getLevels();
    let _query = {
      category: props.settings.cats,
      limit: 15,
      ordering: "-date",
      published: 1,
      display_skill: hsks,
      taxon: props.taxon,
    };
    _query = processDates(props, _query);
    setQuery(_query);
  };

  const processMetaData = async (data) => {
    if (data) {
   ... some data processing here, including copying data to _data.
      setArticleGroups(_data);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    processMetaData(data);
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
   loadArticlesByCategory();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading || articleGroups?.length === 0) {
    return (
      <Flex
        flexGrow={1}
        _dark={{
          bg: "gray.700",
        }}
        _light={{
          bg: "gray.100",
        }}
        alignSelf="center"
        justifyContent="center"
        w="100%"
        minH={500}
      >
        <Loading />
      </Flex>
    );
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      zIndex={-1}
      data={articleGroups}
      renderItem={(articleGroup, index) => (
        <CardRow
          articleGroup={articleGroup.item}
          count={index}
          key={index}
          cardForm="WhiteCard"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

const CategoryArticles = memo(CategoryArticlesChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've tied yourself up in knots!

Let's clean that up.

As a general rule, state should live in one, and only one place. That looks to be in the categoriesSlice reducer. So let's delete localCategories, and selectedCategories and instead, derive selectedCategories.

By removing all of the unnecessary useEffect hooks, we should be able to dramatically cut down the number of additional renders.

### Update:

Let's put back the local state for selectedCategories, so that we can "update" the component ui, and then asynchronously dispatch an update to redux.

In order to simplify the initialization of the selectedCategories state, let's split the component in two, where the top level component is responsible for loading the data, and then handing it down to the select component for initialization of state.

```
export const CatsModal = (props: any) => {
  /**
   * Available categories from an api
   */
  const { data, status } = useCategoriesAPIQuery({ taxon: props.taxon });

  /**
   * If the api query is pending, render a Box
   */
  if (status === 'pending') {
    return <Box />;
  }

  return <SelectCategory data={data} />;
};

const SelectCategory = ({ data }: any) => {
  /**
   * Now that react-redux hooks are standard, lets useDispatch, and useSelector, and drop the connect pattern
   */
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  /**
   * Selected Categories in redux state
   */
  const categories = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.categories);

  /**
   * A Category is selected if it is in the selected Categories redux state, and exists in the available Categories list
   */
  const initialState = categories.filter(
    (category) => data.find((item) => item.value === category) !== undefined
  );

  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState(initialState);

  /**
   * Asyncronously update redux
   */
  const saveAll = async (categories) => dispatch(categoriesSaveAll(categories));
  
  /**
   * On Change, if the item that was pressed is selected, then unselect it, else select it.
   */
  const handlePress = (value: any) => {
    let next: any = [];
    if (selectedCategories.includes(value)) {
      next = selectedCategories.filter((item) => item !== value);
    } else {
      next = [...selectedCategories, value];
    }
    setSelectedCategories(next);
    saveAll(next);
  };
  return <MultipleSelect items={data} selectedItems={selectedCategories} onPress={handlePress} />;
};
```

Comment: "As a general rule, state should live in one, and only one place" - yes, I am aware of this general rule. I am saying that explicitly in this situation, that isn't working, and the attempt at local state was an attempt to fix it. Making a call to categoriesSaveAll is adding huge amounts of slowdown to the application. This isn't due to a bunch of renders, it's due to an API call that is also dependent on the categories slice.

There's precedent for this in a few places: 

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32867

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35037

Comment: Also I tried your solution, the same problem (UI/UX that is very laggy) is occurring. When categoriesSaveAll is removed, that is not the case

Comment: @StevenMatthews okay, let's try a different approach. I don't see in your code where the categories slice api call is happening. But I suspect the problem could be there. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's just because the UI update and the API code call are happening due to the same event, and so they're connected. When I'm trying your code above, I am still getting the lag when SaveAll is in the code. When I comment it out, no lag. I'm going to add my CategoriesArticle component to my question, which is where the actual query is.

Comment: But I definitely think the issue is due to React Native and the fact that API code is getting called at the same time as UI/UX code. I don't think it's a code cleanliness thing - even if those components do need cleaner code (they're a bit legacy, and while they've been upgraded to some extent, they need a full re-write). But the problem isn't excessive re-renders or anything like that. It's a threading issue, I am pretty sure.